# Codename One event listening within a Container which contains more sub-Containers

Tags: java, codenameone

I'm using Codename One to develop a mobile app.

I have an outer-Container which I added an `ActionListener` by invoking the method `addPointerReleasedListener` to it.

There are more inner-Containers which are NOT added with any listeners.

To illustrate:

```
outer-Container (added `addPointerReleasedListener` to it)
 - An Image Container (NO listener added)
 - A Text Container (NO listener added)


--------------------------------------------------------------
| |            |                                             |
| |            |                                             |
| |   Image    |  Some Text here                             |
| |            |                                             |
| |            |                                             |
--------------------------------------------------------------
                                    ^        ^        ^
                                    works only if I click/press
                                    here
```

I noticed that in order to invoke the event, I have to click/press on an area which is not occupied any inner-Containers. That is, it does **not** work if I click/press on any text and image areas (because there no listeners added to it). I have to specifically click/press on an "empty" area of the outer-Container. Obviously, this does not make sense because I want to make the entire container react the same way when the user clicks/presses anywhere within it.

What is the best method/practice to implement this? (I find it a bit redundant to add the same listener to many inner-Containers.)

Comment: Does the answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach won't work properly on real devices.

Create a button and add your `actionListener` to it and set your outer container's `leadComponent` to that button.

```
Button btn = new Button("");
btn.addActionListener(e -> {
    //Your action here
});
outerContainer.setLeadComponent(btn);
```

You don't have to add that button to your container, just set it as the leadComponent only.

Comment: Yeah, that worked. Thanks! However, it is now sending that Button in the getSource() method of the (ActionEvent actionEvent). I have to work around this by instantiating the Listener with a constructor accepting the outer-Container as argument (so I can respond to the correct outer-Container). I don't think this would cause any problem / memory leaks, so I think it is fine. Thanks!